# Embedding ZSSRichTextEditor in UITextView / UIWebView

Tags: ios7, uitextview, rich-text-editor, html-editor

I Would like to embed the [ZSSRichTextEditor](https://github.com/nnhubbard/ZSSRichTextEditor) in UITextView / UIWebView. 
I am having a form with fields which will be filled by the user. One of the fields needs to be formatted by user as in [ZSSRichTextEditor](https://github.com/nnhubbard/ZSSRichTextEditor). I tried the UITexView inline custom formatting. But failed to convert the `attributtedString` to `HTML` and the reverse. Any suggestions please.

Comment: @Nic Even with the UIWebView I could not understand that how to implement it. I am using Xcode 5.1's Storyboard for design purpose. And having a form with 5 fields. Can anyone please explain how to embed it in UIWebView atleast.

Answer (score 0):

`ZSSRichTextEditor` wasn't built to work with a `UITextView`. All the functionality that we built into it requires `UIWebView` to function. It IS an HTML editor.

If you try to force it to work with a `UITextView`, pretty much every function will no longer work.

Comment: Can you please explain how to embed it in UIWebView

Comment: You don't embed it, you need to subclass `ZSSRichTextEditor`. Did you take a look at the demo project? It should be self explanatory if you do.

Comment: Yes of course. What my doubt is: how to embed ZSSRichTextEditor with UIWebView which is present in the form. There's no documentation for it. I could not understand how to implement it. I welcome possible answers.

Comment: @JananiM "Present in the form"? Are you meaning using it as an inline editor?

Comment: @JananiM Using it as an inline editor isn't currently supported.